# Number theory - Divisibility and perfect square related

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative proof that $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square when it's an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer)

I've tried many different approaches and they don't seem to lead anywhere.

The question goes like this :

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers ($> 0$) such that $(1+ab) \mid (a^2 + b^2)$. Show that the integer $(a^2 + b^2)/(1+ab)$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: Thank you all for duplicating >.> After posting it I saw the "related" section on the right but I wasn't able to delete my post for some kind of reason I don't understand yet.