# Prove quotient is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> If $1+ab$ divides $a^2+b^2$ , prove that the quotient is a perfect square.

Tried to use the fact that $\displaystyle\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$ is an integer but I am stuck.

Comment: This is IMO 1988/6 and is asked many times before on MSE.

Comment: For example here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94069/fraca2b21ab-is-a-perfect-square-whenever-it-is-an-integer?rq=1

Comment: And here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Answer (score 2):

It is not so elementary. It is a famous IMO Problem (6th problem of 1988 IMO).

For a solution see [here](http://www.yimin-ge.com/doc/VietaJumping.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply what's called [Vieta jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping), but which is really [descent on conics using reflections.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151641/242) See also [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38528/242)