# if $a,b$ are natural numbers such that $(1+ab)|(a^2+b^2).$ then $\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$ is perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

if $a,b$ are natural numbers such that $(1+ab)|(a^2+b^2).$ then $\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$ is perfect square.please provide some hint.i have tried ,but donot know from where to start

Comment: This is an example in wikipedia's article on [Vieta jumping](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping).

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/645091/242)