# Tough mathematics question

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

If $a,b,q=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ are positive integers then $q$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Hey this is an inmo question

Comment: Let $a=2$ and $b=3$, then $\frac{13}7$ is not perfect square.

Comment: @rubik, your edit isn't same as original question.

Comment: The solution there.  http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056472_one_binary_form  For the case which you said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative proof that $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square when it's an integer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer)  Also a link [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94069/fraca2b21ab-is-a-perfect-square-whenever-it-is-an-integer)

Comment: @Mathematician171 You're right, I'm sorry. Thanks for noticing.