# To prove $\frac {a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a perfect square , without geometry or induction.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab+1$ divides $a^2+b^2$ ; then prove that $\frac {a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a perfect square (this problem came in $\Bbb {IMO}$ $1988$). How to prove it without using geometry or induction ?

Comment: Search the MSE site for IMO 1988. You will get a number of hits, several highly relevant.

Comment: Would any of the dozen solutions posted and linked to [e.g. here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28438/11619) answer your question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Uh,thank you.

Comment: NP. This **is** a fun problem! It is just kinda famous :-)

Comment: please check this (second proof)
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yeah I know , I just now proved it by extremal principle.

Comment: New and better solution without using vieta jumping method here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer/646382#646382