# Find every pair of integers $(p,q)$ such that $ \frac {p^3 -q}{pq+1} $ is an integer

Tags: divisibility, integers

> Find every pair of integers $(p,q)$ such that $ \dfrac {p^3 -q}{pq+1} $ is an integer.

I have tried few pairs, and came with few answers. But I couldn't come with proper solution.

Comment: What are the solutions that you found?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy $(q^3 ,q) $ as an example.

Comment: $$\dfrac{q(p^3-q)}{pq+1}=p^2-\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{pq+1}$$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Comment: $\frac{30^3-8}{8*30+1} = \frac{26992}{241} = 112$, $\frac{240^3-27}{240*27+1} = \frac{13823973}{6481} = 2133$. Last but not the least, $\frac{418^3-112}{418*112+1} = \frac{73034520}{6481} = 1560$. The pattern doesn't seem clear at all.

Comment: Ok wait, also check with $p=5822, q = 1560$.

Comment: Why, this must be some sort of Vieta jumping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p,q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$\frac{p^3-q}{pq+1}=r \iff \frac{p^3-r}{pr+1}=q$$

Note that $q$ and $r$ are symmetric in roles,

take $q=a_{k+1}$, $r=a_{k-1}$ with $p=a_{k} \,$,

$$a_{k+1}=\frac{a_{k}^3-a_{k-1}}{a_{k} a_{k-1}+1} \iff
  a_{k-1}=\frac{a_{k}^3-a_{k+1}}{a_{k} a_{k+1}+1}$$

Take $a_{0}=0$ and $a_{1}=n$, that reproduces what **Ivan Neretin** found.

In particular, for $n=1$,
$$a_{k}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sin \frac{\pi k}{3}$$

And for $n>1$,
$$a_{k}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4-4}}
\left[
  \left( \frac{n^2+\sqrt{n^4-4}}{2} \right)^k-
  \left( \frac{n^2-\sqrt{n^4-4}}{2} \right)^k
\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

Take any integer $n$. Consider a linear recurrent sequence:
$$a_0=0$$
$$a_1=n$$
$$a_{i+1}=n^2\cdot a_i-a_{i-1}$$
The first few sequences are:
$$\{0,2,8,30,112,418,1560,5822,21728\dots\}$$
$$\{0,3,27,240,2133,18957,168480,1497363\dots\}$$
$$\{0,4,64,1020,16256,259076,4128960\dots\}$$
Then any pair of subsequent terms (in any order) is a solution. Note also that if we take $(a_i,a_{i+1})$ as our $(p,q)$, the integer they produce is $a_{i-1}$, and if we consider $(p,q)=(a_{i+1},a_i)$ instead, we get $a_{i+2}$.

I'm not sure whether this covers *all* solutions, though. But I strongly suspect it does.

Comment: You could start with $a_0=0$ to make it simpler and to include the trivial solution p=0.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.