# Vieta Jumping: Related to IMO problem 6, 1988: If $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$ then $ab + 1$ cannot be a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, vieta-jumping

The famous IMO problem 6 states that if $a,b$ are positive integers, such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$, then $\frac{ a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1 }$ is a perfect square, namely, $gcd(a,b)^2$.  How about a modification of this problem:

- If $a,b$ are (strictly) positive integers, such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$, then $ab + 1$ cannot be a perfect square.

I am looking for a proof of the claim above, or a counter-example.

One possible approach towards a proof is the following:

Suppose there is such a pair $(a,b)$ as above, then by the famous IMO problem 6 from 1988, $\frac{ a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1 } = g^2$ where $g = gcd(a,b)$. Since $ab + 1$ is a perfect square, $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ for some integer $c$. So that $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean tripple, therefore there exists positive integers $n,m,l$ with $n$ coprime to $m$, such that $a = l(n^2 - m^2)$ and $b = 2lnm$ - by Euclids formula.

Then by plugging in $a$ and $b$ in terms of $n,m,l$ into the original equation, and solving for $l$, it is possible to obtain the following:

There exists positive coprime integers $n,m$ such that

$\frac{(n^2 + m^2 + 1)(n^2 + m^2 - 1)}{2mn(n+m)(n-m)}$ is a perfect square.

If we put the quotient above into a program, as in this python code snipet:

```
N = 1000

for n in range(1,N):
    for m in range(n+1, N):
        A = (n*n + m*m + 1)*(n*n + m*m - 1)
        B = 2*m*n*(n+m)*(m-n)
        if A % B == 0:
            print(A/B)
```

The quotient always is 2, regardless of whether or not $n$ and $m$ are co prime! So if the very strong implication

- $2mn(n+m)(n-m) \mid (n^2 + m^2 + 1)(n^2 + m^2 - 1) \implies \frac{(n^2 + m^2 + 1)(n^2 + m^2 - 1)}{2mn(n+m)(n-m)} = 2$

holds, then the original problem will be solved.

Comment: Can these formulas to use.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1308326_the_case_with_rational_coefficient

Comment: They might be of use, thanks!

Comment: how do you know that the value of $k = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}$ is $\text{gcd}(a,b)^2$?

Comment: Here is a link to a proof: http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjJwJr91o3QAhXM6RQKHT_6BZgQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wfnmc.org%2Fmc19882campbell.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFxotOTkz1gAOSyOLI221NGautBDA&sig2=wXMs298DYd281k_bSq2dqw&bvm=bv.137901846,d.d24

Comment: I have reduced your problem so finding a solution over the integers to a pair of quadratic forms.  This is likely a very difficult problem.  Very little information I could obtain on Google for this topic.

Comment: @cactus314 of $m$ and $n$ exactly one is odd, and the one that is even is divisible by $8$. Use that $(n^2+m^2+1)/2$ is odd (use that odd$^2-1=0\mod4$). The recursive sequence $M_0=0,M_1=1,M_{k}=2M_{k-1}+M_{k-2}$, produces $0,1,2,5,12,29,70,169,408,985,2378,5741,13860$,etc, nonzero consecutive values give $n,m$ for which the fraction  $\displaystyle\frac{(n^2+m^2+1)(n^2+m^2-1)}{2mn(n+m)(n-m)} = \pm2$. Googled it: https://oeis.org/A000129 Pell numbers, sometimes also called lambda numbers.

Comment: There is a related problem which I listed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998292/pythagorean-tripples-and-pell-numbers  which is thanks to @Mirko's observation of the relation between Pell numbers and our. The claim there is stronger then the claim here, as it implies that the above is true

Comment: Above I meant that "the one that is even is divisible by 8" *provided* that $k$ is odd, where we assume that the ratio $\displaystyle\frac{(n^2+m^2)^2−1}{2mn(n^2−m^2)}=k$ is an integer. A possible substitution to consider: Let $n^2=x$, $m^2=y$, $nm=z$, then we get $(x−kz)^2+(y+kz)^2=2z^2(k^2−1)+1$ the degree in this equation is smaller, but has one extra variable,has $x,y,z$ rather than just $n,m$, considering $k$ a parameter. If $k=2$ then the only solutions are Pell's numbers, since then $n=±\sqrt{2m^2±1}+m$, e.g. $m=2,n=\sqrt{2m^2+1}+m=5$, or $m=5,n=\sqrt{2m^2-1}+m=12$. OP suggests $k=l^2$.

Comment: It is also possible to show that the only integer solutions $n>m > 0$ to $\frac{(n^2 + m^2)^2 - 1}{2nm(n^2 - m^2)} = 2$ are consecutive Pell-numbers by noticing that if $(n,m)$ is a solution to the above equation, then so are $(n + 2m,m)$ and $(m,n-2m)$.

Comment: @Michael Hoefnagel : I am sorry for the inconvenience with my post, I have deleted it. I will only undelete it, if I found the right solution completely.

Comment: No worries, I hope you manage to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit of a hacky answer to your question in the *affirmative*

You observe that $k = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)^2$.  After plodding through various resources, it is because one can Viete Jump:

$$ (a,b) \mapsto  \big(a_1, b_1\big) \mapsto \dots  \mapsto (k,0) $$

and the gcd [is](http://www.wfnmc.org/mc19882campbell.pdf) conserved. Once I agree with you, let $a = \text{gcd}(a,b) \, c$ and $b = \text{gcd}(a,b) \, d$ so that
\begin{eqnarray} ab+1 &=& \frac{a^2+b^2}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)^2}= c^2 + d^2  \\
&=& \,\text{gcd}(a,b)^2 \, cd + 1
\end{eqnarray}

In this way there are two conditions $c, d$ might solve (where the two $\square$ are different) and $\text{gcd}(c,d)=1$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
c^2 - \square \, cd + d^2 &=& 1 \\
c^2 + d^2 &=& \square
\end{eqnarray*}

Hopefully these two equations leads to a contradiction.

---

*Added 11/15* The answer is definitely **no**.  Let $k = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ We are trying to solve in integers:

\begin{eqnarray} c^2 - k\; cd + d^2 &=& 1  \\
c^2 + d^2 = \square
\end{eqnarray}

As I learned, the first can be solve with $(c,d) = (1,0)$ or $(k,1)$ and there are an infinite family of solutions using consecutive terms of a recursive sequence [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016031/show-that-k4-k2-1-neq-n2-can-never-be-a-perfect-square), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015221/solve-x2-25-xy-y2-1-does-it-have-a-solution)]
$$ x_{n+1} = k \, x_n + x_{n-1} $$
There are sometimes ways to link Pythagorean triples to Pell equations [[1](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~alperin/pt.pdf)] (**Modular Tree of Pythagoras**)

$$  x_{n+1}^2  + \frac{1}{2} x_n^2 < \sqrt{x_{n+1}^2 + x_n^2 } = x_{n+1}^2 \sqrt{1 + (x_n/x_{n+1})^2} < x_{n+1}^2  + \frac{1}{2} x_n^2 + 1$$

This cannot be an integer.  So any time we solve the Pell equation, we cannot also solve Pythagoras. $\quad\quad\square$

---

#### Old Answer

This is discussed on Wikipedia's article on [Vieta Jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping):

> Nobody of the six members of the Australian problem committee could solve it. Two of the members were George Szekeres and his wife, both famous problem solvers and problem creators. [...] The problem committee submitted it to the jury of the XXIX IMO marked with a double asterisk, which meant a superhard problem, possibly too hard to pose. After a long discussion, the jury finally had the courage to choose it as the last problem of the competition. Eleven students gave perfect solutions.

Among the eleven was Bau Chau Ngô (Fields Medal 2010).  His work on the Fundamental Lemma also has a jumpy flavor [[1](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~ngo/survey.pdf), [2](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/SL2.pdf), [3](http://www.math.toronto.edu/arthur/pdf/icm-ngo.pdf)] but is quite advanced.

The discussion on YouTube is helpful as well.  These videos give a thorough discussion of different ways to solve

- [The Legend of Question Six](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y30VF3cSIYQ) (Numberphile)
- [The Return of the Legend of Question Six](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Vj_7Y2-xY) (Numberphile2)

These may not directly solve your problem but provide historical context and indicate possible strategies.

---

In the **Wikipedia** article, the example of Viete Jumping is IMO 1988/6 -- the same as asked in the question:

> Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $ab+1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$ show that $ \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}$ is  a perfect square.

and the solution goes in three steps

**#1** Let $a, b \geq 0$ be solutions to  $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1} = k$ such that $k$ is not a perfect square: $k \neq \square$

**#2** Starting from $(a,b)$ we can try to generate another solution $(x,b)$ which solves the quadratic equation:
$$ x^2 - kb\, x +(b^2 - k) = 0 $$
The map $(a,b) \mapsto (a_1,b)$ is our **Vieta jumping** Since both $a, a_1$ are acceptable solutions we have:
$$ (x-a)(x-a_1) = x^2 - (a + a_1) x + aa_1 = 0$$

By the Viete equations (comparing the coefficients. We find out two things:

- $ a + a_1 = kb $ so that $a_1 = kb - a \in \mathbb{Z}$ (it is an integer)
- $ aa_1 = b^2 - k $ so that $a_1 = \frac{b^2 - k}{a} \neq 0$

**#3** If $a \geq b$ we can deduce that $a_1 \geq 0$ (is positive) and additionally $  a > a_1 \ge 0 $

- From #2 $ a_1 = \frac{b^2 - k }{a} < \frac{b^2}{a} < \frac{a^2}{a}=a $
- $\frac{a_1^2 + b^2}{ab+1}= k > 0 $ implies that $ a_1b+1 > 0$ or $a_1 > - \frac{1}{b}$ but $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $a_1 \geq 0$.

**Summary** We've show that given two positive numbers $a,b$ solving $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=k$ with $k \neq \square$ we can **always** find another solution $(a_1,b)$ solving the same equation with $a > a_1$.

Then the Viete jump consists of a map:

$$ (a,b) \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{rc}
(b,a) & \text{ if } a \leq b \\
(\frac{b^2-k}{a},b) & \text{ if } a \geq b
 \end{array}\right.$$

---

While this does **not** solve your problem -- to show that $ab+1 \neq \square$ -- it does indicate possibly where to start and some possible resources.

A quick use of Bezout formula shows that $ab+1$ should also divide 
$$ \big[(a^2 + b^2) + 2(ab+1)\big] + 
\big[(a^2 + b^2) - 2(ab+1)\big] = (a+b)^2 +(a-b)^2  $$

and this could lead to your contradiction.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Comment: Thanks for this, it will definitely be of help.

Comment: No problem, it does seem to be quite challenging. Good luck!

Comment: @Mirko I rearrange the equation $ \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}=k = \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)^2$ so that 
$$c^2 + d^2 =  \frac{a^2 + b^2}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)^2}=ab+1 $$ 
My definition is that $(c,d) = \big(\frac{a}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)}, \frac{b}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)}\big)$.