# An Identity for Pell-numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The Pell-numbers are defined recursively by:

$P_0 = 0,  
P_1 = 1$ and $
P_{n+2} = 2P_{n+1} + P_n$

I am stuck trying to prove the identity:

$P_{2n+1}^2 - 1 = 4P_n P_{n+1}(P_{n+1}^2 - P_n^2)$

A proof would be great, otherwise a list of known Pell-identies would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a well-know Pell-identity: $P_{2n+1} = P_n^2 + P_{n+1}^2$ which can be found in [this](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj5poyRp5LQAhUM7RQKHVfrAb4QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fq.math.ca%2FScanned%2F9-3%2Fhoradam-a.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF3HThNCbieoh3iM21UQAyeH5ggUw&sig2=M-ncXO4Sa1ISBtFaF2R-SA) paper. It can also be shown directly.

Using this, we just need to show: $(P_n^2 + P_{n+1}^2)^2 - 1 = 4P_n P_{n+1}(P_{n+1}^2 - P_n^2)$

This is done by induction: The statement clearly holds for $n = 0$, therefore suppose it holds for any $n$ and consider the following argument:

$(P_{n+1}^2 + P_{n+2}^2)^2 - 1 = (P_{n+1}^24P_{n+1}^2 + 4P_nP_{n+1} + P_n^2)^2 - 1$

$= 16P_{n+1}^2(P_n + P_{n+1})^2 + 8P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1})(P_n^2 + P_{n+1}^2) + (P_n^2 + P_{n+1}^2)^2 -1$

$= 16P_{n+1}^2(P_n + P_{n+1})^2 + 8P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1})(P_n^2 + P_{n+1}^2) + 4P_n P_{n+1}(P_{n+1}^2 - P_n^2)$

$= 4P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1})(4 P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1}) + 2 P_n^2 + 2 P_{n+1}^2 + P_n(P_{n+1} - P_n))$

$= 4P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1})(P_n^2 + 5P_{n+1}P_n + 6P_{n+1})$

$= 4P_{n+1}(P_n + P_{n+1})(P_n + 2P_{n+1})(P_n + 3P_{n+1})$

At this point, we can just apply the fact that $P_n + P_{n+1} = P_{n+2}$, and
$P_n + P_{n+1} = P_{n+2} - P_{n+1}$ and substitute that into the above equation:

$4P_{n+1}P_{n+2}(P_{n+2} - P_{n+1})((P_{n+2} + P_{n+1}) = 4P_{n+1}P_{n+2}(P_{n+2}^2 - P_{n+1}^2)$

which completes the induction.

Answer (score 0):

You know $P_{n+2} = 2 P_{n+1} + P_{n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $P_{n+2}-(1+\sqrt{2})P_{n+1}= (1-\sqrt{2})(P_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt{2})P_{n})$. In other word, we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{P_{n+2}-(1+\sqrt{2})P_{n+1}}{P_{n+1}-(1+\sqrt{2})P_{n}} = (1-\sqrt{2}).
\end{align*}
Since $P_0 = 0, P_1 = 2, P_2 = 2$, we deduce that 
\begin{align*}
P_{n} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^n - (1-\sqrt{2})^n }{2\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}
You refer to [Pell_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number).

Comment: Thanks, I did see this on the wikipedia page