# How to prove it is a perfect-square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, square-numbers

Let $ x $ and $ y $ be two positive integers.
Prove that

$$(xy+1) | (x^2+y^2)\;\implies \frac{x^2+y^2}{xy+1}\;\text{ is a perfect square}$$

I assumed there exists $ k\in \Bbb N $ such that
$$x^2+y^2-k(xy+1)=0$$
or
$$x^2-kyx+y^2-k=0$$
i said that the discriminant $$\Delta=k^2y^2+4k-4y^2$$
must satisfy
$$\sqrt{\Delta}\in \Bbb N$$
but it seems to complicate .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative proof that $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square when it's an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer)

Comment: Thank yo so much.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping) has an article devoted to this problem and the technique used to solve it.

Comment: Ah yeah this was the famous question 6. The method used to solve it is called "Vieta Jumping" - it's a form of contradiction. The solutions to the equation are connected in some way, and you show that, using the way the solutions are connected - that the expression must be a perfect square (otherwise you contradict some minimality condition). It's super genious