# How correct is my solution for IMO 1988 Problem 6?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

Problem #6 at IMO 1988: Let a and b be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$. Prove that
$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$
is a perfect square.

Let this perfect square be $n$.

$a^2+b^2=n(ab+1)$
$a^2+b^2-abn-n=0$
$a^2-(bn)a+(b^2-n)=0$
$a=\frac{bn+\sqrt{b^2n^2-4(b^2-n)}}{2}$
$b^2n^2-4(b^2-n)$ must then be a square for $a$ to be an integer.
$4(b^2-n)=4b^2-4n$ is then a difference of two squares, and
$n$ must be a square as $4b^2$ is already a square.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your argument in the last line would conclude that since $5^2 - 4^2 = 6^2 - 27$, it should follow that $27$ is a perfect square...

Comment: No, not good. Why must $n$ be a square if $4b^2$ is already a square? Compare with the beautiful solutions at the various [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative proof that $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square when it's an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer)

Comment: For what it is worth, I explored the link in the comment of @JitendraSingh.  I had trouble following some of the proofs.  In that link, you can to to the answer by Amir Parvardi (current score = 33), and take the very 1st link in his answer.  This takes you to an AOPS article that contains several proofs.  In this AOPS article, the specific proof that I was able to follow was a **descent argument** by [james digol : may 18, 2010].

Comment: Ah I see. I missed that, thank you!